# Unexpected result from CTE on cyclic data

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hierarchical] (
    [id]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] INT           NULL,
    [name]      NVARCHAR (40) NULL
);
```

Containing some data:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[hierarchical] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (9, 11, N'43EB7203-3A7F-49A9-8C58-F18738D2BBC4')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[hierarchical] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (10, 9, N'E202CAFA-4C0D-4A84-B02A-BF53AC3AFAB1')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[hierarchical] ([id], [parent_id], [name]) VALUES (11, 10, N'371C28E0-8C54-4A23-B28A-273979810E54')
```

As you can see the hierarchy is cyclical 9 => 11 => 10 => 9.

I'm trying to create a CTE that can handle this cyclic data like this:

```sql
alter procedure GetHierarchicalTree
    @rootid int
as begin
    ;with computed as (
        select H.id, H.parent_id, 1 lvl, '[' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']' pat
        from hierarchical H
        where id = @rootid
        union all
        select H.id, H.parent_id, C.lvl + 1, C.pat + '[' + CAST(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']'
        from computed C
        inner join hierarchical H on C.id = H.parent_id
        where C.pat not like '%[' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']%'
    )
    select * from computed
    option (maxrecursion 0)
end
```

The guard clause is the `where C.pat not like '%[' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']%'` so if the ID is already included then stop.

But when running the stored procedure on ID number 9:

```sql
exec gethierarchicaltree 9
```

The sp returns 9 and 10, but not 11, which is odd because 11 shouldn't be in `computed.pat` already.

Running on 11 returns 9 and 11, but not 10.

Even more puzzling is running on 10, because the sp only returns 10.

Why the sp doesn't return 9 and 11?

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that a child Id can be a substring of a parent. In your Method you would stop even though the child is new

Comment: Fiddle here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/33292/1

Comment: Pls see my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `LIKE`, the square brackets `[]` should not be there:

```
where C.pat not like '%' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + '%'
```

UPDATE:

I understand you use the brackets to delimit your path. In that case you have to escape the opening bracket like this:

```
where C.pat not like '%[[]' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']%'
```

Comment: OMG I didn't realize that [square bracket has special meaning in like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql)! OK I'll use another delimiter or I'll use charindex like @PeterHe suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the where condition to use charindex: 
 CHARINDEX('[' + cast(H.id as nvarchar(max)) + ']',C.pat)=0

Answer (score 0):

Your data has circular reference; 11 is the parent of 9, which is the parent of 10, which is the parent of 11, which is the parent of 9, which... That isn't a hierarchy and actually infers there's a design flaw somewhere.

I *suspect* what you want is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetHierarchicalTree @rootid int
AS BEGIN
    WITH rCTE AS
        (SELECT H.id,
                H.parent_id,
                CONVERT(varchar(MAX), QUOTENAME(H.id)) AS [name]
         FROM dbo.hierarchical H
         WHERE H.id = @rootid
         UNION ALL
         SELECT H.id,
                H.parent_id,
                r.[name] + CONVERT(varchar(MAX), QUOTENAME(H.id))
         FROM rCTE r
              JOIN dbo.hierarchical H ON r.parent_id = H.id
                                     AND h.ID != @rootid)
    SELECT *
    FROM rCTE
    --OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); --As you have a circular reference I strongly recommend this OPTION. You could very overwhelm your server.

END;

GO
EXEC dbo.GetHierarchicalTree 9;
```